# Как подключить и использовать Telegram Bot API — PHP SDK в Yii 1.x?

Tags: php, yii, telegram-bot, composer

Имеется старый проект на Yii 1.1.19 - изначально ставился не через Composer

Понадобилось использовать в нём PHP-либу: [Telegram Bot API - PHP SDK](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk)

Был установлен Composer по [инструкции](http://urmaul.com/blog/how-to-attach-composer-to-yii-project/).

Далее:

> php composer.phar require irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk ^2.2

Прописал в protected/config/main.php строку:

> require_once( dirname(**FILE**) . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');

в коде пишу:

> use Telegram\Bot;
>
> $telegram = new Api('My_KEY');

получаю:
include(Api.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

что не так? Почему Api.php не находит? Он же лежит в /vendor/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/src/Api.php

**Что я пропустил?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фак, я использовал:

> $telegram = new Api('My_KEY');

вместо правильного:

> $telegram = Telegram\Bot\Api('My_KEY');